# Escaping Closure in Swift VS Delegate Types in C#

Tags: c#, swift, closures

I'm coming from a C# mindset when I started to learn Swift very recently. I found it very hard to understand that if a Swift function wants to store a closure type parameter, it has to be marked as `@escaping`.

In C#, such equivalence does not require delegate type parameters to be marked with any special keyword if the delegate will be stored and invoked later outside of the current scope.

What is special about Closures in Swift that requires the `@escaping` keyword? Any implementation details regarding this language feature would be great.

Comment: @escaping is used when the closure is called after the function it is an argument to has finished executing. But I can't say why/how this is special for Swift since I don't know C#

Comment: The key is that we distinguish `@escaping` from non-escaping closures in Swift because there are certain optimizations that the compiler can perform with non-escaping closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing particularly special about escaping closures in Swift. The keyword is there to tell the caller of an API that the closure will live beyond the scope in which the the API was called. This has important implications for memory management in Swift.

There is no true garbage collector in Swift. You're probably aware that you can have a strong reference or a weak reference. A strong reference is one where, as long as it exists, the object referenced cannot be deallocated. A weak reference is one where the object can be deallocated even while it still exists.

For example:

```
class A
{
    var foo: B?
    weak var bar: B?
}

class B
{
    var foo: A?
    weak var bar: A?
}

var a = A()
do 
{
    var b1 = B()
    var b2 = B()
    a.foo = b1
    a.bar = b2
}
```

In the above, `a` holds a strong reference to `b1` and a weak reference to `b2`. When the scope of the `do` exits, `b2` will be deallocated, but `b1` will live on because `a` has a strong reference to it.

If I do this:

```
b1.foo = a
```

now `a` has a strong reference to `b1` and `b1` has a strong reference to `a`. These objects will not be deallocated when they go out of scope because each has a strong reference to the other. It's called a reference cycle  and it's a major source of memory leaks in Swift. They way to get around it is to designate one object as the "owner" of the other and make the reference from the owned to owner  a weak reference.

A closure is an object in Swift that has as its properties the block of code to execute and references to the variables it captures. These are strong references by default. So this closure:

```
{ () -> () in print(a) }
```

captures `a` as a strong reference. This is fine but there is a problem. It's easy to accidentally create reference cycles. Consider the following:

```
class C
{
    private var frobnicator: () -> () = { }

    func doFrobnication()
    {
        frobnicator()
    }

    var aString = "a value"

    func setFrobnicator(_ closure: @escaping () -> ())
    {
        frobnicator = closure
    }

    func temporarilyFrobnicate(_ closure: () -> ())
    {
        closure()
    }
}

let c = C()
c.setFrobnicator{ print(c.aString) }
c.temporarilyFrobnicate{ print(c.aString) }
```

In both of the above calls, `c` is captured by the closure with a string reference. This is fine for the second case. The closure has a strong reference to `c` but nothing has a strong reference to the closure. The closure does not escape the scope of `temporarilyFrobnicate`. But, in the first case, `c` has a strong reference to the closure and the closure has a strong reference to `c`. We have a reference cycle. It's important for a programmer calling a function like `setFrobnicator` to know that the closure escapes the scope of the function so they can make the capture references weak e.g.

```
c.setFrobnicator{ [weak c] in print(c.aString ?? "") }
```

The problem is particularly pernicious with `self` e.g. if you try this:

```
extension C
{
    func doSomething()
    {
        setFrobnicator{ print(aString) }
        temporarilyFrobnicate{print(aString) }
    }
}
```

it doesn't look like you have created any reference cycles, but by using `aString` you actually capture `self`. This is why the compiler flags an error on `setFrobnicator{ print(aString) }` to make you explicitly write `self` so that it is obvious you have captured it and that you should make sure it is captured weakly.

```
extension C
{
    func doSomething()
    {
        setFrobnicator{ [weak self] in print(self.aString ?? "") }
        temporarilyFrobnicate{print(aString) }
    }
}
```

The compiler does not error the second call because it knows that the closure is not escaping, just like you do.